# Migration magento problem

Tags: magento-1.7, migration

I want copy a magento installation in hosting to update in localhost.

I copy all files to my localhost and y create database in my localhost. I import all in my database and I changed `core_config_data` in **local database**. But when I access to my url in local, **It has an error**. I copy `error.log`:

> [Thu Dec 29 09:26:09.559916 2016] [:error] [pid 13880] [client
>   192.168.255.24:50420] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in
>   /var/www/web/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php:555\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/web/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()\n#1
>   /var/www/web/web/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()\n#2
>   /var/www/web/web/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52):
>   Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController),
>   'buyshop_home')\n#3
>   /var/www/web/web/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45):
>   Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController),
>   'buyshop_home')\n#4
>   /var/www/web/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419):
>   Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()\n#5
>   /var/www/web/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')\n#6
>   /var/www/web/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176):
>   Mage_Core_Controll in
>   /var/www/web/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 555

I read in other pages that I have to change this file, but It the same that y have in the hosting, I think that If y copy the same, this should run good.

**What I can do?**

Thanks.!

Comment: Verify that, for migration you also change in local.xml file in your localhost.

Comment: Which php version you are using on local i think its php 7